# run rabbitmq on windows

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I was using rabbitmq on Windows about 6 months ago, now I am reinstalling rabbitmq and erlang but I get this error:

```
C:\Program Files\new_RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.8.12\sbin>rabbitmq-server


Configuring logger redirection
12:49:39.059 [warning] Using RABBITMQ_ADVANCED_CONFIG_FILE: c:/Users/ALFA RAYAN/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/advanced.config

12:49:39.810 [error]
BOOT FAILED
12:49:39.810 [error] BOOT FAILED
===========
12:49:39.810 [error] ===========
ERROR: distribution port 25672 in use by another node: rabbit@Ali
12:49:39.810 [error] ERROR: distribution port 25672 in use by another node: rabbit@Ali

12:49:39.810 [error]
12:49:40.826 [error] Supervisor rabbit_prelaunch_sup had child prelaunch started with rabbit_prelaunch:run_prelaunch_first_phase() at undefined exit with reason {dist_port_already_used,25672,"rabbit","Ali"} in context start_error
12:49:40.826 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.150.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,{dist_port_already_used,25672,"rabbit","Ali"}}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}} in application_master:init/4 line 138
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,rabbitmq_prelaunch,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,{dist_port_already_used,25672,\"rabbit\",\"Ali\"}}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,rabbitmq_prelaunch,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,{dist_port_already_used,25672,"rabbit","Ali"}}},{rabbit_prelau

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
```

> i use otp_win64_23.2 and rabbitmq-server-3.8.12

Comment: possibly, when you try to reinstall rabbitmq, before that, you need to stop all processes associated with rabbitmq work? clarify please this moment

Comment: You should stop RabbitMQ from Windows Services

Comment: thanks everyone, i solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to windows services and look for RabbitMQ. Right click on it and stop the service.
Restart the RabbitMQ server in an administrator mode. This worked for me.